# How do you make a ctools modal resizable so scroll bars appear when the content overflows?

Tags: 6, chaos-tool-suite, javascript

I'm using Color Box and CTools modules to create a modal with some content. When the window is extremely short the modal can't be big enough to accommodate the contents, and they are cut off. I would like the modal to use scroll bars when there is overflow (e.g. auto or scroll), but setting the "resizable" option to TRUE does nothing.

Is there another option I can set?